# error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, server, fortran, shared-libraries, gfortran

I am running a Fortran model on a linux server (CentOS8). When I run the .exe file (`./pgd.exe`) compiled by `make`, I got the error message:

```
./pgd.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And if I type `where gfortran`, I got nothing. But if I type `whereis libgfortran.so.3`, I got

`libgfortran.so: /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.5`.

Since this is a server used by many users, I cannot ask the admin to degrade the libgfortran.so.5 to version 3, how can I do to ensure the model running? I searched that there are some similar questions and potential solutions are like `sudo apt-get install libgfortran3`. But I don't know how to install libgfortran3 under my account since I am not the admin and couldn't use `sudo`. Thanks!

Comment: Why not update to the later

Comment: you mean for the fortran model?

Comment: Technically, changing libgfortran.so.5 to libgfortran.so.3 would be a downgrade.  A big downgrade.  You ought to recompile your application with gfortran.

Comment: I am not sure...I am not the developer of the model...I can just follow the model's requirement...

Answer (score 2):

The application ("pgd.exe") has been compiled with an older version of gfortran where the runtime library is not compatible with the runtime library provided by centos 8. There are a number of solutions, such as

- Recompile the application with the version of gfortran provided in centos8.
- Copy the old libgfortran.so.3 somewhere, set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point there so that the application finds it.
- Bundle the application and whatever libraries it needs as a container.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! Now I got it, it's due to the inconsistency between compiled .exe and the new lib in system. But I still have a question. If I need to run the model, every time I need to recompile the model (not the master, just compiling for user). So why should I do that? why not just throw everything essential into one .exe or .sh file?  so that anytime when I need it, I can run it without any compilation?

Comment: There are valid arguments for and against static vs dynamic linking. Look into the issue and choose what works for you.